# ASP.NET OnDataBinding event for EditItemTemplate DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, events, datasource, detailsview

I have a dropdownlist control in an edititemtemplate for a details view defined like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Primary Use">
 <EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPrimaryUseEdit" runat="server" OnDataBinding="DropDownList_DataBinding"
      SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PrimaryUse") %>' ToolTip="Primary Use">
   <asp:ListItem Value="">Unknown</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Manufacturing Facilities</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Residential</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>VSSM Office</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Engineering / Office / Warehouse</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Vacant / Surplus Land</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

I have a datasource definded as a query to my database that has a column named "PrimaryUse". Sometimes there can be a value in the PrimaryUse column that isn't listed as one of the dropdownlist items and so my application crashes when trying to bind the dropdownlist's selectedvalue to that field. I'm trying to create code in the edititemtemplate's OnDataBinding event that will check if the value being returned from the datasource is a valid value listed as an item in the dropdownlist options. My problem is that I'm not sure how to get the datasources fieldvalue for that column in the behind code. Is this possible? Is so, can some one give me an example or point me in the direction on how to do this?

So, in the OnDataBinding event for the edititemtemplate listed above, I would like to do the something like the following (psuedo code):

```
if datasource.datafieldvalue("PrimaryUse") is in dropdownlist.Items then Valid
else set dropdownlist.Selectedvalue = "Default"
```

Comment: what language are you using ?

Comment: vb.net would be my guess, since he has the (if,then,else) going on, but then again its pseudocode

Answer (score 1):

You want to check for valid values in the datasource's onDataBinding event handler. The result of a successful datasource data binding is a List cast from the EventArgs.  If you know a little LINQ you can write some thing like:

```
var validData = ((PrimaryUseTable)e.Results).PrimaryUse.Intersect(DropDownList.Items.AsEnumerable())
if(validData.Any())
{
  //Do Stuff
}
else
// Alternate Stuff
```

Comment: You would probably clean up the above code by assigning the ((PrimaryUseTable)e.Results) to a variable first and then use the variable in your LINQ query.  I added the PrimaryUse column right before the Intersect function.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use Eval() in the codebehind to get this value.  One problem though, is that I think you are trying to do this in the wrong place...  You need to do this in the OnDataBinding (or OnItemDataBound, etc) for the data control, not the DropDownList.  The DropDownList event will not have the correct context, which may be why you are having a problem.

Comment: I'm using C# as my language.

So you're saying that I can use the Eval() in my code behind? Could you provide an example of how you write that statement in the code behind? I'm only familiar with using eval() in the .aspx page:
<%# Eval("PrimaryUse") %>

Also, you're saying that I need to handle this in the OnDataBinding for my datasource? e.g.:
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsFirstView" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" OnDataBinding="sdsFirstView_DataBinding" >

Comment: I'm saying you need to handle it in the DataBinding event for whatever control is holding <TemplateField>, as that where the actual data you are interested in is coming from.